# Eyaml string encryption in Python

Tags: python, encryption, puppet

I am generating puppet hieradata yml files in Python.

I would like to implement the following Ruby code in Python...

```
public_key_pem = File.read(puppet_key_file)
@public_key_x509 = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( public_key_pem )
@cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)


ciphertext = OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([@public_key_x509],
  plaintext,
  @cipher,
  OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY
).to_der
"ENC[PKCS7,#{Base64.encode64(ciphertext).gsub("\n", '')}]"
```

In another module I'm handling certificate sign and key generation with PyOpenssl, but I noticed the encryption methods are not implemented...

---

Potential solution with M2Crypto...

```
from M2Crypto import SMIME, X509, BIO
def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        """
        Encrypt a string using the previously generated public key AES-256-CBC, SMIME PKCS7 envelop

        :param plaintext: The text to encrypt
        :type plaintext: str
        :returns: The encrypted text
        :rtype: str
        """
        buf = BIO.MemoryBuffer(plaintext)
        smime = SMIME.SMIME()

        x509 = X509.load_cert_string(self.certificate)
        certs = X509.X509_Stack()
        certs.push(x509)
        smime.set_x509_stack(certs)

        smime.set_cipher(SMIME.Cipher('aes_256_cbc'))
        encrypted = smime.encrypt(buf)

        out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
        encrypted.write(out)
        buf = out.read()
        buf = buf.strip().replace("-----BEGIN PKCS7-----", '').replace("-----END PKCS7-----", '').replace("\n", '')
        return 'ENC[PKCS7,' + buf + ']'
```

Comment: hi, i am currently also looking for a way to deal with eyaml using python. have you ever created a working implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but a workaround if you have eyaml-hiera installed:

```
import subprocess

PATH = 'd:\\path\\to\\scripts\\'

EYAML = PATH + 'jruby-9.3.7.0\\bin\\eyaml.bat'
DIR = PATH + 'eyaml'  # contains keys\\public_key.pkcs7.pem
    
def encrypt(password):
    args = [EYAML, 'encrypt', '--string', password]

    subprocess.run(args, timeout=10, cwd=DIR)
```

(when I tried to run from the command-line, the substitution was messed up, so can help in that case)